# eclipse on MacOSX :marketplace plugins resinstallation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, macos-sierra, nodeclipse, eclipse-marketplace

[image]I am using eclipse oxygen/Neon on Mac OSx SIerra ,I have installed nodeclipse plugin but when I close my eclipse and start it again. it prompts me for reinstallation for same plugins where as this behaviour is not exhibited on windows.How can I make the installation of plugins as permanent

Comment: Oxygen and Neon are two different versions. Which are you using? What does the prompt look like?

Comment: yeah i know that both are different ,I have tried the same on both the version. first i went to marketplace selected the plugins I wanted to install, then restarted eclipse.Found the new plugins installed.when i closed the eclipse(Quit).When I started he clipse again the found the prompt box similar to the one we get while installation .i.e to accept the terms for install.

Comment: It happens everytime when i start the eclipse after I have performed the installation for the first time.